# change opacity of an element list to 1 and others to .7 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im new in jquery i have tow questions 
the first : i have a list elements contain latest news with time and title of news, i want to create a effet to this list, at the first titles opacity have 1 when hover over an element i want the current element still have opacity 1 and change others opacity to 0.6 like this image [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIh0r.png)

this is my  code

```css
.last-news{
     
     border: 1px solid #636363;
     border-top: none;
     width: 100%;
     height: 409px; 
     overflow: scroll;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .last-news .info-txt{
     margin-right: 10px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     position: relative;
     height: 35px;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-time{
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-time span {
        font-family: verdana !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        color: #F79622 !important;
        height: 33px;
        line-height: 33px;
    }
    
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-time .tiret {
        font-size: 15px !important;
    }
    
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-title{
     position: absolute;
     top: 4px;
     right: 56px;
     width: 212px;
    }
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-title{
     opacity: 0.7;
     transition: 1s opacity; 
    }
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-title:hover{
     opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-title h2{
        font-size: 15px !important;
        color: #26255E !important;
        height: 33px;
        line-height: 33px;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        font-weight: normal !important;
        width: 500px;
    }
    
    .last-news .info-txt .info-txt-title h2 a{
     color: #333333 !important;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="last-news">
                    <div class="info-txt">
                        <div class="info-txt-time">
                          <span>11:11</span>
                          <span class="tiret">|</span>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="info-txt-title .info-txt-title-current">
                          <h2><a href="#">الملك وتعيين الوراق مفتشا عاما للقوات المسلحة الملكية</a></h2>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
    </div>
```

i try to use toggle class() but im still have problem

my second question is : if i want to slide h2 tag to the right to continue reading title how can i do it using jQuery
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   $(function(){
$('.para p').mouseenter(function(){
$(this).css({'opacity':1});
$(this).css({'left':'15px'});
})
$('.para p').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).css({'opacity':0.7}); 
$(this).css({'left':'10px'});
})
})
```

```css
.para p{opacity:0.7;
        position:relative;left:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="para">
<p>
the first para 
</p>
<p>
the second para 
</p>
<p>
the third para 
</p>
</div>
```

```
hope it works for you
```

Comment: @A.hmimou if its so then please accept my answer :)

Comment: now want to slide the h2 tag to right (toggle right) to continue reading title its possible?

Comment: @A.hmimou yups its possible

Comment: can you help me do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have all items set to `opacity:1;`, set each of the items when .items is hovered to 0.7, and set the hovered item to `opacity:1;` like so :

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
</div>

.item{
  position:relative;
  transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
.items{
  opacity : 1;
}

.items:hover .item{
  opacity:0.7;
  padding-left:0px;
}

.item:hover{
  opacity:1 !important;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding-left:20px !important;
}
```

check out this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5fkwmxmv/

the edit with slide animation : https://jsfiddle.net/5fkwmxmv/1/

Comment: no, you do not understand what i want in the first items should have opacity 1 when i hover the current must have opacity 1 other set to 0.7

Comment: is that better?

Comment: now if i want to slide to right the h2 tag when i hover  should i use jQuery ?

Comment: no need for jquery. check out the edit, in an rtl language you should change the padding to `padding-right`

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:
In this situation, it's convenient to manipulate the siblings with the function `.siblings()`, like this:

http://liveweave.com/JCBoag

```
(function($){

  var news_container = $(".last-news");

  news_container.on('mouseenter', '.info-txt', function (event) { 
    $(this).siblings().find(".info-txt-title").css( "opacity", "0.6");
  }).on('mouseleave', '.info-txt', function (event) {   
    $(this).siblings().find(".info-txt-title").css( "opacity", "1");
  });

})(jQuery);
```

For your second question, I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish, but maybe use something like the animate function for repositioning your child element inside it's parent:

```
yourElement.animate({'left': '-=100px'},'slow');
```